# Cannot run java as regular linux user

Tags: java

I am having problems trying to run java as a normal user on linux.  It runs fine as root user but not as a regular user.

Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks

```
root@pro1 [~]# which java
/usr/local/jdk/bin/java
root@pro1 [~]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
root@pro1 [~]# su istream
istream@xxxxxxxxx [/root]# which java
/usr/local/jdk/bin/java
istream@xxxxxxxxx [/root]# java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
istream@xxxxxxxxx [/root]#
```

**Update:**

Yes, limits was the problem.. The server is running cpanel and that is imposing some pretty strict limits on users.

Thanks for the info.

Comment: have you tried, as the regular user, to do 'java -version' while in some other directory than /root?

Comment: Yes it is the same even from the users home dir or form anywhere else on the system.

Have also tried ./java -version form the java bin dir.

Comment: If you installed java from a repository, you'd better notify the maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

Are there any resource limitations in place for the istream user (run `ulimit -a` and compare) which root doesn't have, possibly virtual memory (RLIMIT_AS / ulimit -v) ?

If so, check if it gets applied by /etc/security/limits.conf and if you can make an exception for the istream user.

Comment: `Could not reserve enough space for object heap` means you don't have enough memory. Besides the `ulimit` part, try to start java with `-Xms12m -Xmx12m`. Use this only for the `-version` test. This way the jvm will only allocate 12MB.

Comment: +1, I have also seen this exact problem caused by limits